# HTML email style tags removed in Gmail iOS App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmail, html-email, responsive-emails

I have been running into an issue with HTML emails in Gmail stripping the style tag. The following is my example style tag in the head of the document that DOES work in Gmail in the iOS app. The text is red on desktop and green on mobile in Gmail.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .some-class {
          color: green !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="some-class" style="color: red;">Test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However it breaks if I use a child descendant selector `>` anywhere in the style block, even if I put it in a separate style block, Gmail seems to remove all style blocks. Here is an example where I am using the child descendant selector and Gmail removes all style blocks. The text is red on both desktop and mobile.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style type="text/css">
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .some-class {
          color: green !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
      @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .breaking-class > a {
          color: blue !important;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="some-class" style="color: red;">Test</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions of what I can do here. A few possible successful outcomes to me would be:

1. An approach that works to allow using a child descendant selector in Gmail (best case).
2. An approach that doesn't support the descendant selector in Gmail but where it won't actually break and remove the other css like the `.some-class` class. (Using separate style blocks didn't work for me)

Right now the only thing that works is removing the descendant selector but then it has a lot less specificity for what I need.

Comment: Some more direction given here talking about gmail stripping style tags but haven't seen anything regarding child descendant selectors: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps-2/#gmail_tip5

Comment: Just to be sure, by a style block you mean `<style>...</style>`? I've always seen Gmail remove them block by block, so what you describe is very puzzling. Can you post your other CSS? There are other things that it strips style blocks for, and perhaps that is why it is stripping those other blocks.

Comment: @Nathan I updated the post to have full HTML email examples with more straight forward tests. Hopefully it is more clear now, but yes what you said is true, the child selector `>` in a separate `<style>....</style>` block breaks this responsive styling in the top `<style> block.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice and straightforward to test now

Comment: That worked for me, via Litmus (they use Gmail iOS 14.2). From your code I had to add the breaking-class class and an `<a>` immediately under that, but it worked.

Comment: @Nathan thank you for taking a look. Per your comment about saying it worked, also when adding the class and the `<a>` you are saying everything worked even coloring the `<a>` text blue? That is great news, especially because I can't see anything about child selectors not working online. I am sending the emails through Ruby on Rails and Amazon SES and I wonder if there is an encoding issue or something happening there that is breaking it specifically. Thank you for your help this gives me good direction!

Comment: @stuyam, you could try sending a test somewhere you can pull the source code from and then see if anything untoward is happening on the sending platform end compared to your original. That may help with your debugging and deciding how to get around the issue.

Comment: Good idea @Digital_Frankenstein, maybe mailtrap.io or something.

Comment: That might be able to do it, or Litmus or Email on Acid

Comment: Genius! I used mailtrap and when the email sent this is what I found... `.breaking-class &gt; a`! It converted the `>` to `&gt;`. That will do it. Now I just need to figure out why rails is doing it but good to know the issue lies there and Gmail isn't as bad as I thought it was. Thanks for your help folks. Ill post when I figure out why rails is encoding that way!